# Android application integration

Tags: android

I am new to Android application development, I want to integrate with my app. So please guide me what to do this. I have tried to learn things from internet but still I have found no solution. so please tell me some tips

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry i want to integrate my android app with dwolla

Comment: guide me some tips about it i m new to dwolla

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to integrate with your app?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is here:

https://www.dwolla.com/developers

Comment: i already go throw this link but problem is that i am not in usa and for dwolla integration i have to sign up account anf for sign up account they need usa mobile no